# in Java does transient ignore variable or value?

Tags: java

**Java course assignment:**

when a variable is put transient will serialisation ignore the variable or only the value of the variable.

**Test this.**

How do I test this?

Comment: Create a class with this property, serialize it by saving it e.g. to disk.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  Serialization relates to values of variables within an object.  The value is serializable, the variable only exists at runtime.  Marking a variable as `transient` stops its value being serialized.  When deserialized, the variable will still be there, just set to its default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do something like:

```
public class Test1 implements Serializable {
    private long longValue;
}

public class Test2 implements Serializable {
    private long longValue;
    private transient int intvalue;
}
```

now serialize an instance of each to disk, if the sizes are the same, then you know that transient variable is not serialized at all, otherwise....

Answer (score 1):

If a variable is declared transient it will not be serialized(not stored in bytes stream as state of the Object).

On Deserialization it will get the default value.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to **serialize** a variable declare it as *transient*.
Serialization means saving the state of a variable.
[see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) for detailed example.

Comment: @down voter Didn't get you??

Comment: I was not the down-voter, but did you get the question?